Not receiving messages after reconnecting on mobile, when device lost connection earlier
I use stomClient and SockJS in this way:
const socket = new SockJS(this.authService.getCompleteUrl() + 'chat');
this.stompClient = Stomp.over(socket);
this.stompClient.reconnect_delay = 4000;
this.stompClient.connect({}, function(frame) {
   self.stompClient.subscribe('/topic/chat/'
   ...

This code works fine in Simulator, but an a real mobile device, if I disable internet connection and reconnect and afterwards will send a message, is does not work.
If I reinitialize stompClient than it works like it should.
Does anyone have any hint how so solve this?
